# AngularJS error current.$$route is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've learn about angularjs. But I found error when i set a title.

> My App.js

```
'use strict';
var serviceBase = 'http://www.yiiangular.dev/'
var spaApp = angular.module('spaApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ModuleTesting',
]);

var spaApp_test = angular.module('ModuleTesting', ['ngRoute']);

spaApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/test/index'
    });
}])
.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);
```

This error like

> Error: current.$$route is undefined

and My controller :

```
'use strict';
spaApp_test.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/test/action1', {
        templateUrl: 'views/book/index.html',
        title: 'Action 1',
        controller: 'action1'
    })
    .when('/test/action2', {
        templateUrl: 'views/book/index.html',
        title: 'Action 2',
        controller: 'action2'
    })
    .when('/test/index', {
        templateUrl: 'views/book/index.html',
        title: 'Action Index',
        controller: 'index'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/test/index'
    });
}])
.controller('index', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.message = 'Index Page';
}])
.controller('action1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.message = 'Action I Page';
}])
.controller('action2', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.message = 'Action II Page';
}]);
```

How to make this error solve??

I already set **ng-app="spaApp"** in my `<html>` tag also.

What is the code I have miss? Oh ya, I use AngularJS v1.4.7

Thanks

Comment: Add the html. To get your router working you have to get an ng-view directive called. Obvisouly this won't do it in head section, you should move your ng-app in body tag or html.

Comment: Writing mistake. Should <html> @Walfrat

Comment: it seems like current is defined but not current.$$route, use your browser's debugger and check what does contains the current variable, if possible add it to your post.

Comment: You should place run blog on `spaApp_test` instead of placing it on `spaApp`.. as all routes has been registered in `spaApp_test` module..

Comment: @PankajParkar how to make ?

Comment: @BerthoJoris just add run block to `spaApp_test.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);`

Comment: @PankajParkar When I have tried your code, and I try to access my domain let say : www.testing.dev, angular automatically redirect page to #/test/index but the error still appears when I open firebug

Comment: Error only when access main domain and angular automatically redirect to #/test/index. But when current route in #/test/index and I reload the page error not show

Answer (score 0):

Why is it set in the `<head>` tag? That means that angular will only operate in between that tag. If you want your whole app to be angular enabled then it would need to go on the `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 1.4.2 so we should be close.

$$route looks like it's kind of an internal angular item. If you log out current in your $routeChangeSuccess you'll see that for otherwise paths $$route doesn't exist. What works in this case is to just use current.title in your $routeChangeSuccess and you'll be golden.